# XeLaTeX: Installed Italic font not appearing

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Italics go missing when I change to a font that is installed and I can't figure out why.

Here is the installed font, (as shown in Mac OS's Font Book):
[image]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14.5pt,
paper=a6,
DIV=14,
pagesize]{scrartcl}                 
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{BentonModernFour}
%\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{BentonModernFour-Roman}% Doesn't work
%\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text} %Works
\begin{document}

No one gave their real names but \textit{nommes de guerre}.

\end{document}
```

Yields only this:
[image]

I've looked at: [including own fonts in xelatex with fontspec doesn't work for "bold" "italic" font faces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302951/including-own-fonts-in-xelatex-with-fontspec-doesnt-work-for-bold-italic-fo)

But this doesn't work for me. I've also looked at [Fontspec can't find italic font (installed later) but will use condensed (installed first) on OSX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214025/fontspec-cant-find-italic-font-installed-later-but-will-use-condensed-instal)

which explains how to update the font cache for LuaLaTeX, but not XeLaTeX. LuaLaTeX yields the desired output, but XeLaTeX does not. 
How can I fix this?
Here is the log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kb86n5as1sog613/mwe%2Bitalics%2Bxe.log?dl=0

Apparently, this is a recurring problem. Here's someone on a different forum from 2012: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20135

Adding ItalFont=(name of font)as a fontspec option didn't work.
As did ItalicFont=*.otf (see image)[image: Ita]

[image]

Comment: Don't use `xltxtra` and `xunicode`

Comment: Deleting xlxtra and xunicode did not fix the problem.

Comment: If fontspec can't find a shape, use the key ItalicFont to set the font manually.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: syntax? ItalicFont=*? See edit above.

Comment: fontspec has a documentation. Did you check it?

Comment: In one of the referenced threads, there was a cite to section 4.2 of the documentation. Unfortunately, that citation is incorrect as section 4 deals with miscellaneous other issues. So I'm looking through the whole thing. There are 96 references to the term "italics". In short, I haven't finished.

Comment: @MichaelKane You don't have to read 96 references. You only have to read pages 10 to 12 which explain font selection by name and by file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

a) Select font by name:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[UprightFont       = *-Roman ,
             BoldFont          = *-Bold ,
             ItalicFont        = *-Italic ,
             BoldItalicFont    = *-BoldItalic ,
             Ligatures=TeX]{BentonModernFour}
\begin{document}

No one gave their real names but \textit{nommes de guerre}.

\end{document}
```

b) Select font by file:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path=/path/to/font/files/ ,
             Extension = .otf ,
             UprightFont       = *-Roman ,
             BoldFont          = *-Bold ,
             ItalicFont        = *-Italic ,
             BoldItalicFont    = *-BoldItalic ,
             Ligatures=TeX]{BentonModernFour}
\begin{document}

No one gave their real names but \textit{nommes de guerre}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: You can find a more detailed explanation on how font selection works in the [fontspec-manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf)

Comment: Indeed it did. But why does "ItalicFont=*.otf" not work?

Comment: You can either specify the font by name (what we're doing here) or by filename. In that case you have to provide the full filename, extension, *and* the path to the fonts.

Comment: The problem is that the issue only occurs sporadically. Sometimes, merely identifying a font family works without more, e.g., "\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}" Other times, even though the different fonts are installed in the same directory, italics or bold do not display correctly. It is even stranger when LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX compiles yield different results with respect to the generation of italics. All of this can not be random behavior, there has to be a reason why one works and the other doesn't. –

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{BentonModernFour}[
  UprightFont    = *-Roman,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]
\begin{document}
foo \textit{bar}
\end{document}
```